# Angularjs stripping trailing slashes

Tags: angularjs

I have a function in a controller:

```
  $scope.deleteTodo = function(id) {
        $http.delete('/musicians/' + id)
            .success(function(data) {
                $scope.todos = data;
                console.log(data);
            })
            .error(function(data) {
                console.log('Error: ' + data);
            });
    };
```

I call it like this:

```
 <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" ng-click="deleteTodo(todo._id)" >
```

It gives 404 error with the url:

```
http://localhost:3000/musicians55accbce27e2cd2802de4894 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

However, it should have been:

```
http://localhost:3000/musicians/55accbce27e2cd2802de4894
```

I also tried adding:

```
.config(['$resourceProvider', function($resourceProvider) {
  // Don't strip trailing slashes from calculated URLs
  $resourceProvider.defaults.stripTrailingSlashes = false;
}]);
```

But it did not fix the issue either and I still have the same problem.

Here is the flow to call it:

```
 app.delete('/musicians/:id', musicians.delete);
```

and

```
exports.delete = function(req, res){
  var id = req.params.id;
  Musician.remove({'_id':id},function(result) {
    return res.send(result);
  });
};
```

Comment: I think the urls are same

Comment: @SimoEndre: There is a slash after musicians in second one .

Comment: Do you not need to escape the slash after musicians?

Comment: No. I am using REST API so I need it there.

Comment: From the code you posted, I don't think it's angular stripping anything. The result of `'/musicians/' + id` will be string which angular will not manipulate when issuing the request. Maybe the server at `/musicians/` is doing some redirects? Could be that these are set up incorrectly. Check the console (network tab) to see what is happening.

Comment: Thank you.I have updated the server side code in question. Could you please consider having a look.

Comment: You must have some redirection happening on server side... Do check the server...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the problem is, but have you tried compiling the url string before the call to `$http`, and see if that fixes it? For example:

```
$scope.deleteTodo = function(id) {
        var url = '/musicians/' + id;
        $http.delete(url)
            .success(function(data) {
                $scope.todos = data;
                console.log(data);
            })
            .error(function(data) {
                console.log('Error: ' + data);
            });
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a stab in the dark but have you tried using the raw `$http` method?

```
$scope.deleteTodo = function(todoId) {
    return $http({ 
        url: '/musicians', 
        method: 'DELETE', 
        data: { id: todoId }
    });
}
```

Comment: still the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to escape the fragment:

```
$scope.deleteTodo = function(id) {
    $http.delete('/musicians\\/' + id)
        .success(function(data) {
            $scope.todos = data;
            console.log(data);
        })
        .error(function(data) {
            console.log('Error: ' + data);
        });
};
```

However, I would suggest to revaluate how you are calling your delete method. You want to be calling the delete of the resource item itself and by not passing the id of the resource into a catch all delete method. See   http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource

Comment: Can you check which call is actually being made to the server then, in your developer tools? (See chrome developer tools > Network > XHR > click call > check request URL)